# What backend does Jenkins (Hudson) use for archiving build artifacts?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, artifacts, jenkins, binaries

I've read about the [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709372/alternative-to-binaries-in-subversion) (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531442/is-it-acceptable-good-to-store-binaries-in-svn/534863#534863)) of using SVN to store build artificats (large binary files).  [Hudson was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709372/alternative-to-binaries-in-subversion/709384#709384) as an alternative.

How does Hudson handle these files?

*Edit:* My project is not Java-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson is basically using flat file storage. You can find those files within Hudson in the jobs/builds/ folders. I'm not sure I'd say, "Use Hudson as an alternative to checking in file to source control" but using something as an alternative is a decent idea if it provides:

1. authoritative place to store
2. versioned binaries access control
3. checksums for tamper resistance
4. release meta-data (environment information; approval level)
5. retention periods

I'm not sure how well Hudson scores on those marks, but I think it does at least some of that. SVN is non-terrible as a solution there as well, but really struggles with retention periods (old builds tend to eat disk space like crazy) and isn't terribly well optimized for large binaries - most SCM systems are optimized for smallish text files.

I stole the list above from this presentation: http://www.anthillpro.com/html/resources/webinars/Role_of_Binary_repositories_in_Software_Configuration_Management.html (registration required)

Answer (score 4):

Hudson can create/keep an archive of build artifacts, and provides a nice browser view for inspecting them.

You need to enable **Archive the Artifacts** in the job definition.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We use Jenkins for our builds, but we also store the artifacts from the builds. Like Eric said above, Hudson/Jenkins store artficats using flat file storage. It is organized based on the build.

Some things I have noticed from use (in reponse to Eric's questions about an alternative to souce control for binaries):

- Each build stores it's own artifact, so you do have a versioning of sorts.
- You can use the fingerprinting option when archiving. This will allow you to differentiate between versions and also check for corruption.
- Retention periods are completely up to you. We keep artifacts forever.

FYI, our projects are not Java either (they are C/C++) and our artifacts are tar.gz/zip files and documents.

It may or may not be the *best* way to store binaries, but it is definitely decent as long as you have regular backups (weekly in our case) and your disk is fault tolerant.